# Is there a way to include sitemap from a sitemap url instead of robots.txt in storm crawler?

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

How can we consume a sitemap in storm crawler served through a url, instead of robots.txt 
In my case the sitemap is served as an url with .xml extension. (Some sites that I'm planning to crawl do not have robots.txt)

Answer (score 1):

StormCrawler handles sitemaps just like any URL: you can inject it into ES (if that's what you use as a backend), or take it as a see URL. SC will fetch it and parse it with the sitemap parser bolt. You can help the latter by adding "isSitemap=true" to the metadata of the URL so that it does not have to detect that it is a sitemap.